How does Air Vibrate in a Tube with Holes?
Lets say you have a stringed instrument with a single 1m long string, which is plucked 0.2m along its length. If you place a finger at 0.8m it will make a different sound, because you have shortened the length of the standing wave vibrating the string. However, if you place a second finger at 0.9m the sound will not change, because the length of the wave is not changing. That all makes sense to me and if fairly easy to demonstrate.
Woodwind instruments are frequently described in the same way:

Since being exposed to the air pressure outside the instrument is what is important, the "open end" of a wind instrument, as far as the sound waves are concerned, is the first place that they can escape - the first open hole. This is how woodwinds change the length of the wave, and the pitch of the note... As mentioned above, woodwind players get different notes out of their instruments by opening and closing finger holes, making the standing wave tube longer or shorter. Once the player has used all the holes, higher notes are played by overblowing, which causes the next higher harmonic of the tube to sound. (source)


Woodwind instruments have a long, thin column of air. The lowest note is played with all the tone holes closed, when the column is longest. The column is shortened by opening up holes successively, starting from the open end... In woodwind instruments, the effective length is changed by opening and closing finger- holes or keyholes along the side. This is the way pitch is changed within the same register of the instrument: all holes closed gives the lowest note, and opening the holes successively from the bottom end gives a chromatic scale. (source)

However, this behavior is not observed. For a very simple example, look at a diagram of finger placements of a recorder. If you start at the lowest note, the first 5 notes follow the pattern described by the physic texts. The pattern breaks on F, which needs the ringfinger and littlefinger holes covered even though the earlier middlefinger hole is open. After that, things just get very complicated. Compare F# and G in the lower or higher octave, G# and A in both octaves, B-flat and B in both octaves, or D and E-flat in the higher octave*. This site acknowledges that complications exist due to holes and links to this paper, but I had a lot of trouble understanding it. Page 6 starts talking about open holes, but I get absolutely lost at, "The array of open tone holes and the short sections of bore connecting them thus behave like inertances and compliances in a finite element transmission line."
Can someone offer a simpler explanation for how holes in a pipe effect sound propagation and standing waves?
*Notes in the higher octave are played with the thumb partially covering the hole. This is called an octave hole and is very briefly described here. I get the sense that this phenomena is different from the core question I am asking, which is why I didn't point out that many notes are raised an octave just by changing the placement over the octave hole.
